# Send value of variable that is in a loop from one script to another script

Tags: python

I've been fiddling with sending a variable from one script to another and have done some basic things pretty easily, but I have gotten stuck and was hoping to get some input.

This is my script1.py

```
import time
x = 0

while x < 100:
    x = x+1
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is my script2.py

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("python script1.py", shell=True)

from script1 import x

print(x)
```

The output of this is just 100.

Is there a way to print the variable `x` every time it gets updated through script2.py?

The reason for all of this is I am reading data from a serial port in a script but I want to use the output in a different script whenever it comes in. So essentially, whenever there is data available from the serial port stored in a variable I want that variable passed to another script.

EDIT: I have a python script where it script reads data from one serial port and logs the data.

With that being said, I want a second script that can take the list containing the data from the first script in order to manipulate it for a different task.

EDIT 2:
I have modified the code as follows, but nothing prints.

```
#script 1
import time
x = 0

while x < 100:
    x = x+1
    print(x)
    time.sleep(1)

#script 2
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','script1.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    print(line)
```

Comment: So, are your two scripts linked through a subprocess/pipe, or do you want to import one into the other? Your current approach makes little sense either way.

Comment: My scripts are linked through a subprocess. What kind of approach would make sense? I am still new to python so there is a lot I'm unfamiliar with.

Comment: If your scripts communicate through a subprocess/pipe, you need to communicate the value through that pipe; e.g. `script1.py` writes to stdout and `script2.py` reads from the first script's stdout pipe. You would then also not `import x from script1`, since that circumvents the entire subprocess/pipe.

Comment: Do you want the second script running all the time?  Or do you want only the first script running all the time, and have the second script run every time the data changes?

Comment: @deceze I am looking into piping and not using import.
little_birdie I was planning on having both always running...is that a bad idea?

Comment: Import won't work at all.. it doesn't work like that.  You have to use a pipe, socket, or run the second program each time with the value passed on the command line...

Comment: @little_birdie so I cannot do `import subprocess` like in my EDIT 2? Is it possible to write the variable from script1 to a buffer and read the buffer in script2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Thanks to going back and forth with Vadim, I was able to learn how some of this stuff works. Below is what my code is.

script1.py:

```
import sys, time
x=0
while x<10:
    print(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    x = x+1
    time.sleep(1)
```

script2.py:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('python script1.py', 
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        )
while True:
    output = proc.stdout.readline()
    if output == '':
        break
    else:
        print output.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
0 #waits one second
1 #waits one second
2 #waits one second
.
.
.
8 #waits one second
9 #waits one second
```

Answer (score 0):

main.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import sys

p = Popen(['py', 'client.py'], stdout=PIPE)
while True:
    o = p.stdout.read(1)
    if o:
        sys.stdout.write(o.decode('utf-8'))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print '*'
    else: break
```

client.py

```
import time
for a in xrange(3):
    time.sleep(a)
    print a
```

OUT:

```
0*
*

*
1*
*

*
2*
*

*
```

Comment: I am a bit confused by this. I have two separate scripts, not a function called in a script. Is it possible to modify this so it would be in two different scripts?

Comment: ['ping', '127.0.0.1'] is "different scripts"

Comment: Thanks for the change. I attempted to run and got the following:
`python test_threading.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_threading.py", line 2, in <module>
    with Popen(['ping', '127.0.0.1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: I am still getting weird errors. Is it possible this is only for Python 3? I am using 2.7.10

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Popen(['py', 'client.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True) as p:
AttributeError: __exit__`

Comment: try this variant :) yes i'm use 3

Comment: The error is gone, however nothing is printed. I attempted to put a print statement before and after `r = p.stdout.readline()`. It seems like the script gets stuck at `r = p.stdout.readline()`. Also, thank you for the help.

Comment: I tried it on 3 different computers. One PC, one Mac, and one Linux. Each produce no output. Just blank every time. Any idea why?

Comment: I made a modification `p = Popen(['python', 'client.py'], stdout=PIPE)
` which make it print. However, this brings me back to square one. Nothing is printed until the loop is done. I would like to print after each loop iteration. I put `time.sleep(1)` in the `client.py` loop and that makes is wait 3 seconds then prints everything at once.

Comment: something like this. '*'-main, numbers-client

Comment: Unfortunately, that still prints everything at once. What I want the output to do it print 0 then wait 1 second then print 2 then wait one second then print 3.

Comment: I finally got it. I used a lot of the knowledge you shared. I was able to learn what the programs and methods were doing through all of your examples and I finally got it! Thanks for your help.