# Why does this code work for someone else, but not me?

Tags: python

I am trying to run code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998988/send-value-of-variable-that-it-in-a-loop-from-one-script-to-another-script/38999199?noredirect=1#comment65357051_38999199) answer. For convenience, the code is below.

main.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['py', 'client.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
r = True
while r:
    r = p.stdout.readline()
    print r
```

client.py

```
def fn():
    for a in (0, 1, 2):
        print a
fn()
```

OUTP:

```
b'0\r\n'
b'1\r\n'
b'2\r\n'
b''
```

The person who contributed the answer said it works for them. However, I cannot get it to produce an output. I attempted this with python 2.7 on Mac, Linux, AND Windows.

If this works for you, please explain why it is not working for me. All I am doing is `python main.py` in the directory where both files are.

EDIT: "OUT:" is what I am supposed to get. However, I get nothing.

Comment: That code does not match the expected output. Looking at the edit history of the answer you got it from, the code seems to have been changed repeatedly without testing it each time.

Comment: I do not get an output when I run the code. What is above is the most recent version of the "provided solution". The OUT: is what he gets/what I am supposed to get.

Comment: At the end, print r.returncode - did the subprocess complete successfully?

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment under that answer, not a new question?

Comment: wait, yeah, you've already commented there and gotten replies from people.  why does this question exist?

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE :/ The guy said it works for him. However it does not work for me. I tried on multiple computers and want to understand what I am doing wrong as a python user to avoid having this problem again. After multiple attempts of commenting back and forth, he could not help. So I am trying to get others' input.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this?

main.py

```
from subprocess import check_output

client_output = check_output(['python', 'client.py'])
print client_output
```

---

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

You should look into the `Popen.communicate()` method.

Maybe something like this:

main.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', 'client.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: That produces 0 1 2 and works for me. Why is this the case?

Comment: I know you can't put blocks of code into comments. Nevertheless, this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @BadProgrammer:  could be because of `python` instead of `py`.  Do you have a program, alias, or symbolic link called `py`?

Comment: @cdarke I modified it to python, still no output.

Comment: @BadProgrammer I can't replicate your problem. If you're running different scripts for the client that might be where problems are happening. For instance, if you client requires some user input, the process will hang.

Comment: I am running the exact script, no mods have been made except python instead of py.

Comment: Does using `communicate()` fix your problem?

Comment: @zachyee using sys with stdout.flush fixed it!